# Inputing '\' before a character in a string Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I'm trying to insert a '\' into a string array before each '_' in the string.  The reason I am trying to do this is to keep the format of the sheetnames I pull from an xls file when i use the sheetnames in the legend of a plot.  I tried using:

```
  legend(sheetname{n},'Interpreter','none','Location','East')
```

but it just adds the two commands as two other labels in the legend.  Hense this solution.  I have looked into searching through sheetnames and have found how to replace, but I don't want to replace the characters if possible.  If there is a way to do this please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
legend(sheetname(n),'Interpreter','none','Location','East');
```

Note the use of parentheses instead of curly braces, which passes a cell to [LEGEND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/legend.html) instead of the *contents* of the cell (i.e. [cell indexing instead of content indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-117.html)). This should allow the additional parameter/value pairs to be properly interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply a string replacement function on each cell element, you can do this as follows:

```
cellfun(@(x) strrep(x,'_','\_'),sheetname,'uniformoutput',false)
```

this applies `strrep(x,'_','\_')` to all elements of `sheetnames` and outputs it as a new cell array (because of `'uniformoutput',false`).